# Numba cuda Possible mix of compiler/IR from different releases

Tags: cuda, numba

I've been trying to run some numba/cuda code, like this module:

https://github.com/Maghoumi/pytorch-softdtw-cuda/blob/master/soft_dtw_cuda.py

However I run into the following error:

```
numba.cuda.cudadrv.error.NvvmError: Failed to compile

IR version 1.6 incompatible with current version 2.0
<unnamed>: error: incompatible IR detected. Possible mix of compiler/IR from different releases.
NVVM_ERROR_IR_VERSION_MISMATCH
```

I guess I installed incompatible versions for some packages, but have no idea where to start. Which packages are concerned?

Comment: I am guessing you have installed the CUDA 12 toolkit. I don't believe that Numba will work with that version of nvvm. Use a CUDA 11.x toolkit in that case

Comment: You guessed correctly ! I downgraded to CUDA toolkit 11.8 and it works. Do you know any document about compatibility between numba and cuda versions ? I'd be happy to reward your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying reason for this appears to be using CUDA 12.

According to the [CUDA 12 release notes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#cuda-compilers):

> NVVM IR Update: with CUDA 12.0 we are releasing NVVM IR 2.0 which is
> incompatible with NVVM IR 1.x accepted by the libNVVM compiler in
> prior CUDA toolkit releases. Users of the libNVVM compiler in CUDA
> 12.0 toolkit must generate NVVM IR 2.0.

From the error, it would appear that the Numba CUDA backend is generating NVVM IR 1.6, and from the release notes for CUDA 12, NVVM IR 1.6 is no longer supported by the NVVM compiler library supplied in CUDA 12.

In the short term, use CUDA 11.x or earlier. In the longer term, report this as a bug to the Numba developers and get them to update their compiler infrastructure to match the CUDA 12 NVVM requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the error message wasn't really detailed enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just install **numba** through `conda install numba/label/dev::numba` or build from source.See [Numba Support for Cuda 12](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/8715)

It works fine.